# why does a reply appear as a new topic?

Tags: google-groups

I have a Google Group where I organize only by topic (not category).  Sometimes a reply to `Topic X` will appear as a new topic, `Re: Topic X`.  And this can happen more than once, so that there are multiple `Re: Topic X` topics listed in the web interface.  This seems to happen not just with email replies, but also with web interface replies.

Why is this happening.  Can I turn it off?

Comment: Is this something you have experienced first hand, or something that only appears to inflict your users?

Comment: @w3d It has happened once to me.  Unfortunately, I do not recall if there was anything different in my behavior.  Specifically, I try to always use the web interface, but I wonder if I answered that one by email instead.

Answer (score 1):

## Short answer

If this happens only sometimes could be a [glitch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glitch).

## Alternatives

As consumer account users we could only post a question as a issue report to the [Google Groups - Google Apps for Work Help Forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!categories/apps/google-groups-for-business). As Google Apps for Work or similar account user you could ask the organization admin to submit a support ticket.

If this happens always the group owner or administrator should check the group settings.

## References

[Change how your group’s topics are displayed - Groups Help](https://support.google.com/groups/answer/2646853?hl=en)